# using jquery to bring images from bottom to top of "stack"

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover, z-index

I have three images that overlap. When the cursor moves over one of the images I want that image to hop to the top of the stack. I've tried two methods: the css pseudo-class :hover and jquery.

```
$('.icon-stack').hover(function() {  
     var index = $(this).css("z-index");  
     $(this).css('z-index',index+=3);},  
function() {  
     var index = $(this).css("z-index");  
     $(this).css('z-index',index-=3);  
 });
```

To talk it out a bit more: When mouseenters the bottom image is bumped up to z-index:4, then dropped back to z-index:1. The middle image is bumped up from 2 to 5, the top image starts at z-index:3 so each image should rise above it when the function runs.

I'm getting some behavior: the middle image comes to the top and stays on top.

Comment: I totally mis-read what is going on on the page. The code does work as expected, I have an image shape issue that I didn't realize.

Comment: Then Delete the question thanks .

Comment: @icicleking  Shape issue aside, your code only sort of works sometimes, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your markup and CSS, it is difficult to tell for sure, but I strongly suspect that the issue is `z-index` is being ignored because the default positioning of an element `static`.  You should try setting `position: relative` to the elements in question in your CSS.

Comment: This can't be the case due to the statement " the middle image comes to the top and stays on top."

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).css("z-index")` returns a string.  So `"3" + 3` = 33, etc.  The `-=` does work because `-` has no meaning with strings.  Use `parseInt`.

```
$('.icon-stack').hover(function() {  
     var index = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);  
     $(this).css('z-index',index+3);},  
function() {  
     var index = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);  // not strictly necessary
     $(this).css('z-index',index-3);  
});
```

I also removed the `=` and made it just `+` and `-` as the assignment piece was unneeded.

http://jsfiddle.net/7qGy5/